# Two-Class-Logistic VS Binary Logistic Regression

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

During a test project on Azure Machine Learning Studio I have some questions based on my understandings.
In my project (in R) I have used Binary Logistic Regression, but in AML I found two Logistic regression Two-Class and MultiClass. So in that case I have used two-class Logistic regression. Am I Right in this case?

In another case during running glm() in R tool it perform Logistic regression and after summary(loreg Eqn) it provides the each variable's co-efficient & estimates.

From R I have the following output:

[image]

From AML after right-clicking Train Model and visualize:

[image]

The weight in the above Picture is the estimates, am I right (Dataset is diff)?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, Two-Class Logistic Regression is the same as Binary Logistic Regression, so you're right in that case.

For your second question, no they're different.

Comment: Then How should I get the estimates in AML??